# Cross Referencing list of addresses to custom google maps

Tags: python, google-maps, street-address

I would like to find for every address in my list, what is the constituency that the address belongs to.

I have found this map, that lists the constituency by location
https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=12vZFyd7VqJyI2v5XOhBK5olnPnw&ll=1.343725467746546%2C103.87371266459195&z=12

My addresses are of the form

```
Marine Parade Central
Marine Vista
```

etc. I can geocode them to obtain latitude longitude as well.

Manually, you can key this address into the map, then find out which constituency it belongs to. Is there a way to automate this process? I've only used the heatmap layer before, and downloading the map is only available in KML. If only there was a simple API for this.. If there was a python way to go about this, would be preferable,  but anything that works really.

Would be really grateful if someone can guide me on this! :)

Comment: There are databases, accessible with API from the web, that convert street address to lat/long coördinates.

Comment: @boardrider Hi, I know that. I'm not asking about geocoding. I'm asking about say even after i geocode, how would i map it to the custom map above to get the constituency it falls under :)